# D3DCompileFromFile function throwing exception and not working?

Tags: c++, windows, shader, direct3d, directx-12

I recently tried to pick up DirectX12 and already ran into my first issue. The  `D3DCompileFromFile` function just doesn't seem to work. I am using it as follows:

```
ComPtr<ID3DBlob> vertex_shader_blob;
throw_if_failed(D3DCompileFromFile(L"basic_vertex_shader.hlsl", nullptr, nullptr, "main", "vs_6_5", 0, 0, &vertex_shader_blob, nullptr));
```

I have the `d3dcompiler.h` included, the `d3dcompiler.lib` linked and have the `d3dcompiler_47.dll` in the same directory as the `.exe`. My working directory is set to the correct path and the `D3DReadFileToBlob` function works perfect using the same file name (of course using the `.cso` file and not the `.hlsl`). My entry function is called `main` and the `vs_6_5` target works fine when using the built-in Visual Studio compiler.

What I have already tried:
Changing the path to the full system path, which doesn't change the ourcome. I originally had compile flags (`D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG`), but removed them, however, this also did not change the outcome. Changing to the target to different version such as `vs_5_0`, also doesn't help.

The `HRESULT` output is `0x8876086c`, however, I was not able to find any error code matching this value.

My `throw_if_failed` function is the usual:

```
static inline void throw_if_failed(HRESULT hr)
    {
#ifdef AC_DEBUG
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            throw std::exception();
        }
#endif // AC_DEBUG
    }
```

and the exact console output is as follows:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFD45474F69 in demo.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::exception at memory location 0x0000006AA6FCE2E8.
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFD45474F69 in demo.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::exception at memory location 0x0000006AA6FCE2E8.
```

During the hours spent trying to resolve this issue I also noticed that according to [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3dcompiler/nf-d3dcompiler-d3dcompilefromfile), the `D3DCompileFromFile` function returns a Direct3D 11 return code, even though the website was updated recently? Which makes me question its viability with DirectX12.

Now you might wonder why I would want to use the `D3DCompileFromFile` function if the `D3DReadFileToBlob` function works fine? Well, it's more about principle and finding out where I went wrong to better understand what I am dealing with.

Edit: When using the Visual Studio built-in hlsl compiler, `vs_6_5` works completely fine. Additionally, according to the DirectX Caps Viewer, my GTX 1070 supports `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_1` and Shader model 6.5.

Comment: D3DERR_INVALIDCALL

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I just found the solution: The d3dcompiler is only viable for Shader Model 2 - 5.1. I have to use the [dcx compiler](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler) for anything newer, [this is kind of hidden on the Microsoft docs page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3Mh0.png). (I know that image only shows reflection functions, but the way I understood it in general, is that the dcx compiler is the future) Anyway, I can confirm, that the dcx compiler works perfectly fine.